# About DependencyProperty in WPF

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I'm very new to WPF and while studying (particularly creating a user control), I stumbled upon this thing called "DependencyProperty".

I understand how it works in code but why and when do we need it when I can just create a property and expose it for public use.

Example:

XAML:

```
<UserControl.....>
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
<TextBlock x:Name="label" Text="Hello"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="text" Text="World!" />
</StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

CS file:

```
public partial SampleUserCtrl : UserControl
{
public string LabelText { get { return this.label.Text; } set { this.label.Text = value; } }
public string TextBoxText { get { return this.text.Text; } set { this.text.Text = value; } }
}
```

Comment: If you look at the `dependency-properties` tag here on SO, you'll see that it *'supports databinding, including styles, inheritance, animation, and default values. It allows you to set attached properties on DependencyObject'*. For example, they allow you to set the `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` properties on any element, so a surrounding `Grid` can position them properly. Without dependency properties you'd have to add a `Column` and `Row` property to every possible UI element, which is not feasible.

Comment: Dependency properties *are* properties. The only real difference is that you can use data binding and change notifications with dependency properties in XAML or code. You can't do that with "plain" properties.

Comment: Please do some research before asking a question on StackOverflow. Start reading the online documentation on MSDN: [Dependency Properties Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Been a while since I posted this question.. Took some time to read about databindings and etc. I now understand its purpose and thanks for everyone who posted here. Since I can't accept all the answers below, I'll up vote them instead :D

Answer (score 2):

[DependecyProperty](http://www.wpftutorial.net/dependencyproperties.html) in WPF has different uses.

Advantages compared to normal .NET property

> Reduced memory footprint It's a huge dissipation to store a field for
> each property when you think that over 90% of the properties of a UI
> control typically stay at its initial values. Dependency properties
> solve these problems by only store modified properties in the
> instance. The default values are stored once within the dependency
> property.
>
> Value inheritance When you access a dependency property the value is
> resolved by using a value resolution strategy. If no local value is
> set, the dependency property navigates up the logical tree until it
> finds a value. When you set the FontSize on the root element it
> applies to all textblocks below except you override the value.
>
> Change notification Dependency properties have a built-in change
> notification mechanism. By registering a callback in the property
> metadata you get notified, when the value of the property has been
> changed. This is also used by the databinding.

As you dig deeper to WPF you will also stumble upon [DataBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx) and object-oriented design patterns like [MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level) or [MVPVM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88390/MVP-VM-Model-View-Presenter-ViewModel-with-Data-Bi). Both patterns rely on DataBinding which is achieved through using of Dependency Properties. You cannot perform data binding if it is not a dependency property.

Basically data binding through dependency properties allow the user to update the view when updating a value through code.

Ex: In Windows Forms in order to update a label text you assign its value on the code behind like this:

```
lbl1.Text = "foo";
```

In data binding where as you bind in the XAML (View)

```
<label Text = "{Binding foo}"></label>
```

and update the values in your code behind:

```
foo = "foo";
```

I am not an expert myself so sorry if I might sound confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency property has many benefits over normal property.

- A dependency property value can be set by referencing a resource
- It can reference a value through data binding
- It can be animated. When an animation is
  applied and is running, the animated value operates at a higher
  precedence than any value (such as a local value) that the property
  otherwise has.

You can learn more about it from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752914%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage of DP property you can find anything in DP like your Control info and you current DataContext info.

```
 public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, (s, e) => OnChangedValue(s, e)));

    private static void OnChangedValue(DependencyObject s, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```